# setInterval() not working for making a digital clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/msrumon/pen/KLMZJp) is pretty much self-explanatory of my problem. I'm trying to make a simple digital clock, but it's not ticking for some reasons. This is the portion I'm having problem:

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
setInterval(function()
{
  $("#time").text(time);
}, 1000);
```

Any lead would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move the date and time lines within the function

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `setInterval(function()
{ var date = new Date();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  $("#time").text(time);
}, 1000); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put your date and time variables within the setInterval function, otherwise you're only getting the values once.

```
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  $("#time").text(time);
}, 1000);
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  $("#time").text(time);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<span id="time"></span></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. Such a silly mistake, rather misunderstanding. God bless you.